# The error is saying : "list.appendChild is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, append

```
function addList(value) {
      const list = document.getElementsByClassName("list-div ")
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.classList.add("list-new");
       div.innerHTML = `<div class="h5-div" >
          <h5 class="list" >${value}</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="actions" >
          <span class="action-span" ><button 
                  class="action-btn">done</button></span>
          <span class="action-span" ><button 
                 class="action-btn">edit</button></span>
          <span class="action-span" ><button 
                   class="action-btn">delete</button></span>
          </div>`;

      list.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` would return an array. maybe list[0] will work

Comment: The `list` is an HTML Collection instance and it doesn't have an `appendChild` method. You can't add to the DOM via that interface, to my knowledge; I'm not sure how it could make sense. You'll need to determine where in the DOM you want your new `<div>` to go, and then use DOM node APIs to add it (like `appendChild`).

Answer (score 0):

Preferibly when you are attaching elements to a list with a function, the best option is provide an id instead of a class.
If you want to use the class, you have to use [0] since the "const list" is an array. 
You can't append a child to an array, you need to provide the exact element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list[0]` since `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection (array-like object):

```
list[0].appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know getElementsByClassName returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a HTML Collection. You might need to use list[0] depending on what you wish to do.

```
list[0].appendChild(div);
```

Also, you can consider using `document.getElementByID('uniqueId')` if you wish to get one unique list in your dom. You need to create a list as:

```
<ul id="uniqueId">
</ul>
```